# lualatex with package unicode-math does not work after texlive update

Tags: luatex, fontspec, unicode-math

After the recent TeX Live update (`tlmgr update --all`), LuaLaTeX together with `unicode-math` does not work any more! Here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{unicode-math}

\begin{document}
Hallo Welt!
\end{document}
```

I guess it's because of `fontspec`, which was updated.

Here is the error message:

```
(/mnt/software/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg))(
load luc: /mnt/software/texlive/2015/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/fonts/otf/la
tinmodern-math.luc)
! LuaTeX error .../texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.lua:65: a
ttempt to call field 'sprint' (a nil value)
stack traceback:
    .../texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.lua:65: in function 'ma
thfontdimen'
    [\directlua]:1: in main chunk.
\__um_get_fontparam:nn ...imen("l__um_font","#2")}

l.8 \begin{document}

?
```

Comment: This came up [early today](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/27240590#27240590) in the [chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41/tex-latex-and-friends) and there's already a fix on the way to CTAN. As a temporary measure, adding `\directlua{fontspec = fontspec or {} fontspec.sprint = tex.sprint}` after loading `fontspec` should work.

Comment: Thanks, this workaround is good: Instead of `\usepackage{unicode-math}` one has to write `\usepackage{fontspec} \directlua{fontspec = fontspec or {} fontspec.sprint = tex.sprint} \usepackage{unicode-math}`

Comment: Now, it is fixed through the regular TeX-Live updater.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem was  fixed by package update some time ago